# Trying to grab a variable from one script and apply to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a UI Slider to change the movement speed for my player character using the GetComponent feature. I have everything working except apply the number(float) that I create from the movement of the slider to the variable that controls how fast the player can move.

I've used Debug.Log(); to determine that the variable I'm trying to grab from one script does not equal the other. It almost seems that they're being stored as two separate variables.

The varspeed variable keeps track of the number when I move the slider.

In script BallScript:

```
GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<PointBuyScript>().varspeed = speedvar1;
Debug.Log(speedvar1);
```

In script PointBuyScript:

```
public void Start()
{
    mySpeed.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChangeCheck(); });
}

public void LateUpdate()
{
    varspeed = mySpeed.value;
    Debug.Log(varspeed);
}
```

When I move the slider the number in the console from PointBuyScript scales with the Slider. However, the one from BallScript forever remains the same.

BallScript Code:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BallScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update




    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    public float speedvar1;

    public float SpeedMain;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        speedvar1 = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<PointBuyScript>().mySpeed.value;



    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.00f, moveVertical);

        speed = speedvar1; // this is where I try and update the speed variable to the slider number

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);



    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {


        Debug.Log(speedvar1);
        Debug.Log(speed);
       // Debug.Log(SpeedMain);


    }












}
```

PointBuyScript Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PointBuyScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Slider mySpeed;

    public float varspeed; 

    public float mainSpeed;


    public void Start()
    {
        // GameObject speed1 = GameObject.Find("Ball");

        // BallScript hellome = speed1.GetComponent<BallScript>();

        //  varspeed = GameObject.Find("Ball").GetComponent<BallScript>().speed;










        //Adds a listener to the main slider and invokes a method when the value changes.
        mySpeed.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChangeCheck(); });
    }





    public void Update()
    {

       // Debug.Log(mySpeed.value);



        //mainSpeed = mySpeed.value;


    }


    public void LateUpdate()

    {

        varspeed = mySpeed.value;
        Debug.Log(varspeed);

    }








    // Invoked when the value of the slider changes.
    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {




    }





}
```

Comment: is varspeed actually changing when you move the slider? where in the ball script do you think you're picking up the speed change?

Comment: where is the first code block called?

Comment: I thought that if I changed the value of speed from another script it would automatically update the variable through all of them. If that's not the case then that would probably be why I'm having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<PointBuyScript>().varspeed = speedvar1;
```

Says "take the value in `speedvar1` and assign it *to* `PointBuyScript#varspeed`." That is, the value of `PointBuyScript#varspeed` is changed (and `speedvar1` remains unchanged).

You probably want:

```
speedvar1 = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<PointBuyScript>().varspeed;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still having the same issue.